# What is your prefered major mode for Emacs 24 to work on XML files?

Tags: xml, validation, emacs, indentation

The built in major mode does not suit my needs too well. I would need:

1. autoindentation
2. syntax highlighting
3. validation (based on XML Scheme)
4. Hide/Show of Subtrees

What is your major mode of choice?

Comment: nxml can validate against relax ng schemas - you can convert to them from xml schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nXML is so fully-featured, I can't imagine anyone going to the bother of writing an alternative. In any case, I believe it already covers all these requirements:

- Auto-indentation works just like any other mode -- either use <kbd>M-j</kbd> to start a new line, or bind <kbd>RET</kbd> to the same function, or use `electric-indent-mode`.
- Syntax highlighting is included.
- Validation is included (see Alex Ott's comment re: xml schemas, and also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(nxml-mode) Introduction` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- Hide/Show of subtrees is possible using the outlining support, but this requires some configuration, as it needs to know what  'sections' and 'headings' look like (i.e. it looks like you can't collapse/expand arbitrary sub-trees, but you can probably make it work well enough in most circumstances).

  <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(nxml-mode) Outlining` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Is it also possible to reformat an existing XML document that does not have indentation to make it have some with this mode?

Comment: If you just want to add indentation to the beginning of existing lines, than yes -- just mark the buffer and call `indent-region`. Typically `C-x h TAB` will do this. If you mean taking a file where the elements are all on the same line, and adding newlines at sensible places, than I don't think nXML does that. There are no shortage of utilities which do, however (`tidy` is one example).

Comment: So (after a quick experiment) with tidy installed you can use this sequence to run it in xml mode on the buffer contents, and then re-indent the results: `C-x h C-u M-| tidy -xml RET C-x C-x TAB`